# Java mailto Illegal character colon?

Tags: java, mailto

im trying to send an email with an attachment, but it keeps saying:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 64: mailto:recipient@mailserver.com?subject=ThePDFFile&attachment=C:\Users\Rascal\AppData\Local\Temp\FreelancerList-16-12-2014_09-227568200505392670736.doc
```

Java Code:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop(); 
        String message = "mailto:recipient@mailserver.com?subject=ThePDFFile&attachment=\""+path; 
        URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
        URI uri = URI.create(message); 
        desktop.mail(uri);
```

Should be the colon right? But why???

Comment: the path is this "C:\Users\Rascal\AppData\Local\Temp\FreelancerList-16-12-2014_09-227568200505392670736.doc"

Comment: The error message quite clearly says the problem is at index 64, not index 4. `mailto:` isn't the problem.

Comment: How is your path defined?

Comment: i mean the colon from "C:\"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `URLEncoder.encode`, but ignoring the result. I suspect you were trying to achieve something like this:

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
URI uri = URI.create(encoded);
```

... although at that point you'll have encoded the colon after the `mailto` part as well. I suspect you *really* want something like:

```
String query = "subject=ThePDFFile&attachment=\""+path;
String prefix = "mailto:recipient@mailserver.com?";
URI uri = URI.create(prefix + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));
```

Or even encoding just the values:

```
String query = "subject=" + URLEncoder.encode(subject, "UTF-8");
    + "&attachment=" + URLEncoder.encode(path, "UTF-8"));
URI uri = URI.create("mailto:recipient@mailserver.com?" + query);
```

... or create the `URI` from the various different parts separately, of course.

Comment: Changed it, now it says:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "mailto"

at "desktop.mail(uri);"

Comment: @DenisHartwood: Well did you read the rest of my answer, about only encoding the part that needs encoding?

Comment: After the Error, yes :D
Now it works but i have no Subject and no attachment in my email client...

Comment: So the email.client opens with the email-adress, but without the subject nor the attachment...

Comment: I suggest you experiment with hard-coded URIs then, so you can control all the encoding yourself. I'd start with *just* the subject, and ignore the attachment. It may be that you need to encode each *value* separately rather than the whole query, too...

Comment: i encoded it by mself and replaced all ":" with "%3A" and all "\" with "%5C", still doesnt work. I dont encode the Subject-Part, now the Subject apears in my email-client...

Comment: @DenisHartwood: Right, so you probably want to *just* encode the values: `mailto:recipient@mailserver.com?subject=<encoded subject>&attachment=<encoded attachment>`

Comment: tried it, didnt worked ... Everythink works, except it doenst attach anything. Tried to encode only the path, tried to only replace the ":" and "\"... still doenst attach

Comment: @DenisHartwood: It's not clear from RFC 2368 why `attachment` would work, to be honest. Perhaps this is a URI parameter that only some clients support?

Comment: Tried to encode just the values like in your edit... still doesnt attach. Should i try to use a different path for the file? Not the temp?

Comment: @DenisHartwood: Stack Overflow isn't really aimed at this sort of interactive debugging. I don't even know what makes you think `attachment` *should* work. I've explained how to URL-encode each parameter value - beyond that, for mail-specific URI parameters, you should probably do some more research elsewhere... I'm afraid I don't have any experience in this particular area.